How can I specifically change or replace the HUE for the color red?
My script is not working as I expected. Is there anything wrong with my code?
from PIL import Image
import colorsys

def change_red_to_blue_hsl(image_path, output_path):
    img = Image.open(image_path).convert('RGBA')
    width, height = img.size
    new_img = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height))
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            r, g, b, a = img.getpixel((x, y))
            h, l, s = colorsys.rgb_to_hls(r/255., g/255., b/255.)
            if (h >= 0 and h <= 1/6) or (h >= 5/6 and h <= 1):
                h = (h + 4/6) % 1 
            r, g, b = colorsys.hls_to_rgb(h, l, s)
            new_img.putpixel((x, y), (int(r*255), int(g*255), int(b*255), a))
    new_img.save(output_path)

change_red_to_blue_hsl("C:\\color\\tes.png", "C:\\color\\tes_output.png")

Problem: 
Where input is tes.png then expected result --> the red hue is replaced by a blue hue.
Expectation

Result

I've tried searching from various sources, but I haven't found anything that can specifically change red to blue when dealing with images of a color gradient.

It's not clear what exactly you want to do. Do you want to change one color so that the gradient transitions are preserved?

Certainly, I want that. In my script, it actually already works for the color red. But the issue is, I wrote the script to change the color "red" to "blue," but the script works by changing the color globally (applying hue globally

Your input image goes like this from left to right in HSL colourspace:
Red         Orange      Yellow
0,100,50    40,100,50   60,100,50

and your output image goes like this:
Blue        Green       Yellow
240,100,50  120,100,50  60,100,50

So, the Saturation and Lightness are constant, but you want to map Hues in the range 0..60 into the range 240..60. So, I think you want:
newHue = 240 - 3*OldHue


I've tried it, but it didn't work as I expected. In Photoshop, I usually add HUE and select "red," then decrease its value. And it works for "changing reddish colors." But the script I made seems to work globally. That is, it changes the hue value globally, so other colors whose color change I didn't expect end up changing as well.
